# Request BrowserId : 1 not found it's likely the browser is already closed

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium

При использовании метода `EvaluateScriptAsync` экземпляра класса `ChromiumWebBrowser` возвращает сообщение `Request BrowserId : 1 not found it's likely the browser is already closed`. Библиотека CefSharp. Вот фрагмент кода обработчика события `loadingStateChanged`:

```
    private async void _browser_LoadingStateChanged2(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsLoading)
        {
            JavascriptResponse resp = await _browser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(
                @"document.getElementsByClassName('xt0psk2')[0]['href'];"
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что не так? Какое поведение вы ожидали? Пожалуйста, улучшите свой вопрос.

Comment: @NNL993 Ожидал получить успешное выполнение JS-скрипта. Сообщение, которое я получаю после работы скрипта я уже продублировал в вопросе.

Comment: Отлично, а вопрос в чём? Вы хотите, чтобы за вас сделали код?

Comment: @NNL993 Я не понимаю из-за чего возникает такое сообщение. Возможно я не знаю каких-то нюансов при работе с CefSharp и поэтому я обратился сюда. Я не хочу, чтобы за меня что-то написали.

Comment: Так, хорошо, тогда какие попытки вы предприняли, чтобы решить проблему? Добавьте их в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: @NNL993 Вы вообще работали с данной библиотекой?

Comment: Нет. Я пытаюсь улучшить вопрос, чтобы он следовал правилам сообщества, пожалуйста, прочитайте справку о том, [как задавать хорошие вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @sakyrade ты решил проблему? У меня тоже самое возникло после обновления

Answer (score 1):

У меня была такая же проблема, я без видимых причин иногда получал такую же ошибку. Полагаю это баг в Cefs браузере (вплоть до последней на данный момент версии - 117.2.40).
Попутно выяснил что аналог этого кода, - работает без ошибок:

```
public void ExecuteAsync(IWpfWebBrowser browser, String script)
{
  browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
}
```

Надеюсь этот пример послужит зацепкой для решения вашей проблемы.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/882676)

Comment: It worked for me.